# React: How to use refs in a function component that I have no control over (i.e. from a library)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't believe I couldn't find an answer on this so please point me in the right direction if I am wrong.

---

I am trying to do something simple:

There's a function component from a library that I include.

I need to get a ref to it.

Crucially, React says this:

> Ref forwarding lets components **opt into** exposing any child component’s ref as their own.

Unfortunately, this library component has not opted in using `forwardRef`.

What is the correct approach to get a ref to this element?

The [3rd party library component in question](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics/src/index.js#L16) looks like so (simplified):

```js
function OutboundLink(props) {
  return (
    <a {...props}
        ...
    />
  )
}
```

My component looks like so:

```js
function MyComp(props) {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  return (
    <OutboundLink ref={ref} {...props} >
      {children}
    </OutboundLink>
  )
}
```

but I am greeted with the errors about not being able to pass refs to a function component. Normally I would wrap in `forwardRef`, but can't in this case since I can't modify the library's code directly.

I did see [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) and [this](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1a018a023347fe1c2476073330cc5509) but didn't think either applied to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need the ref after all?

Comment: I want to run mixpanel.track_links() which needs a ref to the a tag

Answer (score 5):

You can't directly. There's no hook to let you in if the component wasn't written that way.

I think your best bet would be to wrap the component, capture a ref, and then drill into its children with DOM methods.

```
const wrapperRef = useRef(null)
const innerRef = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
  if (wrapperRef.current) {
    innerRef.current = wrapperRef.current.querySelector('a')
    // innerRef.current is now the first <a> tag inside <OutboundLink>
  }
})

return <div>
  <div ref={wrapperRef}>
    <OutboundLink {...props}>
      {children}
    </OutboundLink>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Squeegy/pen/gOaabav?editors=0010) (view the console)

But really, this is a bit of a hack. You should use a component that handles this better. Look into how hard it would be to write this component yourself from scratch. It may be trivial, and worth it.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I did just rip the code in the end since, luckily, it didn't have any dependencies. It just seemed unlikely to me that one would be completely at a dead-end. But yes, your hack sounds like the only workaround. Ripping the code was indeed trivial and worth it!